# CS5ServiceManager Java error shows up at startup of Mac

Tags: macos, java

Every time I start my computer a popup window shows up that says

"If you want to open CS5ServiceManager you have to install the older Java SE 6 Runtime"

Why does this show up, and how do I resolve the problem?

I have Mac OS 10.11.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some older software packages require this software. For my Mac's, this is Photoshop. Anyway, Apple has a fix for this. Download and install the software from this the site below and the problem should go away.

[Download Java for OS X 2017-001](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way, if you don't mind getting your feet wet in the Terminal:

`launchctl remove com.adobe.CS5ServiceManager
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.CS5ServiceManager.plist`

What this does is:

Removes the launchctl profile that starts CS5Manager at startup;
Deletes the plist file that re-creates that launchctl profile.

The second step is necessary or it will keep coming back.

Be careful when using sudo and rm, you don't want to remove anything important - just this plist file.

Credit: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1618590